# Validar varios Emails dentro de input a apartir da tecla enter com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

Quero Usar um `input` para armazenar vários emails porem estou com dificuldades pra implantar isso na prática.

ao colocar um email no `input` o usuário tecle enter, para validar o e-mail, se valido adicione o caractere `;`

Como fazer essa ação com jQuery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <input type="text" class="email" id="email">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `keyup()` para pegar evento de enter, utilizar o `split(';')` no ponto e virgula para pegar o ultimo email e também pode utilizar regex abaixo para o validar. A solução abaixo valida o email, se ele for válido adiciona um `;` no final do input, se não estiver correto não faz nada:

```
function verificarEAdicionarEmail() {

    var arrayEmail = $('#email').val().split(';');    
    var eEmailValido = validaEmail(arrayEmail[arrayEmail.length - 1]);

    if(eEmailValido) {
        $('#email').val('');

        arrayEmail.forEach(function(email){
            $('#email').val(($('#email').val() + email + ';'));
        });
    }
}

function validaEmail(email) {
    if(/^([\w\-]+\.)*[\w\- ]+@([\w\- ]+\.)+([\w\-]{2,3})$/.test(email))
        return true;
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#email').keyup(function(event){
        if(event.which == 13)
            verificarEAdicionarEmail();
    });

    $('form').submit(function(){ return false; });    
});
```

Segue [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/fn916ukv/).